# Attaching JQuery Events to "on the fly created" controls

Tags: jquery, attachevent

I'm appending to an existing div in my page. The appended text contains html code in string. The problem is, events aren't working when I add click on them after appending to page. I guess Jquery loads control on page load and I have to do something to attack the events again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or .delegate for this purpose.

Comment: Just an update - both `live` and `delegate` are deprecated. You should use `on` (http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 2):

You are missing [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

So if you run

```
$('#workingArea a.doAction').bind('click', function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

or the equivalent

```
$('#workingArea a.doAction').click(function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

Any `a`'s loaded after that runs don't get the event.

If instead you do

```
$('#workingArea').delegate('a.doAction', 'click', function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

then those events will be captured for any and all future `a.doAction` elements that get added, as long as `#workingArea` exists when it is run.